# SQL Server: Static SELECT vs Dynamic SELECT

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-programming

select 0 from tableA works fine but it does not work in dynamic sql. How do I can fix this ? I must include `@zerocol` in dynamic sql while selecting columns.

```
select top 10 col1,col2,col3,0 
from dbo.tableA

declare @table_name varchar(40)
declare @sqlstr VARCHAR(MAX)
declare @zerocol varchar(20)

set @table_name = 'dbo.tableA' 
set @zerocol = 0
SELECT @sqlStr = ' ; WITH Tableinfo1 AS (SELECT col1, 
col2, 
col3,
['+ @zerocol +'] 

FROM ' + @table_name + ' ) 

SELECT top 10 * FROM Tableinfo1'

EXEC (@sqlstr)
```

Comment: The `select 0` doesn't do what you expect. It uses the value zero in the result, it doesn't get the value of a field named `0`. Do you have a field by that name in the table?

Comment: No, it does not exist in the tableA but I have like 1000 tables. In some tables it exists and in some tables it does not.

Comment: But what does exist? Do you want to return 0 as a number?

Comment: You can't select a field from a table where it doesn't exist. You would need to decide a way to tell in which table there is such a field, and adjust the query so that it only selects that field if it exists in that table.

Comment: i test the above query and it is working fine, nothing wrong with above sql. it return the [0] columns... use "select @sqlstr" to print the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
declare @table_name varchar(40)
declare @sqlstr VARCHAR(MAX)
declare @zerocol varchar(20)

set @table_name = 'dbo.tableA' 
set @zerocol = 0
SELECT @sqlStr = ' ; WITH Tableinfo1 AS (SELECT col1, 
col2, 
col3,
'+ @zerocol +' AS ZeroCol

FROM ' + @table_name + ' ) 

SELECT top 10 * FROM Tableinfo1'

EXEC (@sqlstr)
```